# What is "least common subsumer" and how to compute it?

Tags: algorithm, wordnet

I want to use Wu and Palmer method for computing similarity measure in wordnet,

```
wp = (2 X depth(lcs)) / (depth(synset1) + depth(synset2))
```

where `lcs` is the "least common subsumer" of `synset1` and `synset2`

My question is:

1. What is "least common subsumer"?
2. How to compute it?

Comment: What have you tried? And what do you think are the files required to accomplish this task?

Comment: I want to know that, what is "least common subsumer"?

Comment: So your question is: "What is a least common subsumer?". In that case you should state that clearly, and after that only you ask how to compute that.

Comment: I recommend you to use the [Semantic Measures Library](http://www.semantic-measures-library.org/). It's a java library which implements numerous semantic measures based on knowledge representation analysis, and in particular measures which can be used to compare concepts structured in taxonomy (e.g., measure proposed by Wu and Palmer).

Comment: WordNet is not always a tree. How would you compute the `lcs` if you had multiple ancestors for each node in the pair?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to this [paper](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/N/N04/N04-3012.pdf), Least Common Subsumer of two concepts A and B is "the most specific concept which is an ancestor of both A and B", where the concept tree is defined by the `is-a` relation. A concept is defined to be an ancestor of other concept just like the way you define ancestor in human family tree, which is the parent of the other concept, the grandparents, and so on. For example:

1. A car is an automobile, and an automobile is a vehicle
2. A boat is a vehicle.
3. Vehicle is an object.

And the graph:

```
    Object
      |
    Vehicle
      |
  ---------
  |       |
 Boat  Automobile
          |
         Car
```

In this case, "automobile" is the parent (and also ancestor) of "car", while "vehicle" is an ancestor of "car". "Vehicle" is also an ancestor of "boat". In this case, the LCS of "boat" and "car" is "vehicle", since it's the most specific concept which is an ancestor of both "boat" and "car". Note that while "object" is a common subsumer of both "boat" and "car", it is not the least, since there is still a child of "object" (in this case it's "vehicle") which is also a common subsumer of both "car" and "boat". "Automobile" is not the least common subsumer since it's not an ancestor of "boat".

To compute the similarity measure, I suggest you to use available library, otherwise you will need to build the concept graph yourself, which is troublesome.

In Perl, you can use [WordNet::Similarity package](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WordNet-Similarity/lib/WordNet/Similarity.pm)

In Python, you can use nltk package, specifically, the [`wup_similarity`](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html#nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.Synset.wup_similarity)

In Java, you can use [ws4j package](http://code.google.com/p/ws4j/)

Comment: Thanks for your response, now I want to know that what is the depth of LCS(Boat, Car)? Is it 3 or 4?

Comment: I suggest you read more about Tree ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure) ). Basically the depth is calculated from the root of the tree. Using my graph, the root is `Object`. So, the depth of `Object` is 0. Now, `LCS(Boat, Car)` is `Vehicle`, so the depth is 1.

Comment: It should be "the most specific concept", so it is the furthest down, which is still `Vehicle`

Comment: @justhalf Thanks for answering but I realized that my question was stupid :D it is clear that it has to be the most specific concept since otherwise you would always get a LCS of 1 [since e.g. everything is made up of quarks (or atoms or a basic unit or whatever)] :P